# How get taskToken step function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have sfn with *activity*. I want to get taskToken in lambda, which execute *SendTaskSuccess*.
Multiple sfn start execute. I need to get taskToken for sfn specific execution in oreder to continue it.Method *getActivityTask* returns GetActivityTaskResult starting from oldest sfn execution to newest. It doesn't suit me, if it returned a list of running execution, but no. How can I get needed taskToken for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your question and for your interest in Step Functions.

The **task token** for a Task state can be accessed from the global [Context Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html), and passed to the invoked Lambda function as part of its payload.

Here's what the state definition would look like in the waitForTask token task state example:

```json
{  
   "StartAt":"GetManualReview",
   "States":{  
      "GetManualReview":{  
         "Type":"Task",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
         "Parameters":{  
            "FunctionName":"get-model-review-decision",
            "Payload":{  
               "model.$":"$.new_model",
               "token.$":"$$.Task.Token"
            },
            "Qualifier":"prod-v1"
         },
         "End":true
      }
   }
}
```

See: [Invoke Lambda with Step Functions - AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-lambda.html)